# How would I determine zodiac / astrological star sign from a birthday in Python?

Tags: python, django, date

I am building a dating site in Django / Python. I have birthday dates and need to show what the person's Zodiac sign is based on their birthday.

Anybody done this before? What would be the most efficient way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've done this before.  The simplest solution that I ended up with was an array of the following key/values:

```
120:Cap, 218:Aqu, 320:Pis, 420:Ari, 521:Tau,
621:Gem, 722:Can, 823:Leo, 923:Vir, 1023:Lib
1122:Sco, 1222:Sag, 1231: Cap
```

Then you write the birth date in the `mdd` format, ie, month number (starting with 1 for January) and two digit day number (01-31).  Iterate through the array, and if the date is less than or equal to an item in the array, you have your star sign.

**EDIT**
I needed this so here's this concept as a working function

```
zodiacs = [(120, 'Cap'), (218, 'Aqu'), (320, 'Pis'), (420, 'Ari'), (521, 'Tau'),
           (621, 'Gem'), (722, 'Can'), (823, 'Leo'), (923, 'Vir'), (1023, 'Lib'),
           (1122, 'Sco'), (1222, 'Sag'), (1231, 'Cap')]
def get_zodiac_of_date(date):
    date_number = int("".join((str(date.date().month), '%02d' % date.date().day)))
    for z in zodiacs:
        if date_number <= z[0]:
            return z[1]
```

Comment: +1 - this looks like the best solution that can be done without having to install a new module.

Comment: for the lookup you could use `bisect`, see the example in http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect .

Comment: Using bisect for 13 keys in function that is used not very often is little overoptimised, don't you think?
Moreover log_2(13) is 3.7 so you have only 13/3.7 = 3.5 times less operations. I would be concern that one operation in bisect may take more than 3.5 times than simple loop, so you even have worse performance then.
To sum up, bisect is very good suggestion form most searching cased, but this is probably not the one.

Comment: I would also use a dict, but like this: `d[bisect(d.keys(),121)]`, resulting in "Sag". Not so much for speed, I think it just looks better than writing a loop for that.

Comment: Doesn't look right to me. November 4 is a scorpio. As per above logic: its becomes 1104 which comes out to be less than 1122 eventually giving Libra. This is wrong

Comment: @hellojava heh, you must be the only one here who actually knows the zodiac :)... I've fixed the off-by-one error.

Comment: @bluesmoon was implementing it for our app http://www.matrified.com So while validating the data came across this. :) Thanks for the solution pointer though.

Comment: Instead of `date_number = int("".join((str(date.date().month), '%02d' % date.date().day)))` you can have `date_number = date.date().month * 100 + date.date().day`

Comment: There is a wrong result if I take 31 of December. The function returns None.

Comment: @Fomalhaut change `<` to `<=`

Comment: @bluesmoon in this case, the zodiacs list should be changed to the following to avoid the date comparison bug (22 Dec returns "Sagittarius")

    zodiacs = [(119, 'Capricorn'), (217, 'Aquarius'), (319, 'Pisces'), (419, 'Aries'), (520, 'Taurus'),
    (620, 'Gemini'), (721, 'Cancer'), (822, 'Leo'), (922, 'Virgo'), (1022, 'Libra'),
    (1121, 'Scorpio'), (1221, 'Sagittarius'), (1231, 'Capricorn')]

Answer (score 8):

You could give them some more information about [position of the planets](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/index.html) and the stars.

```
import ephem 
>>> u = ephem.Uranus()
>>> u.compute('1871/3/13')
>>> print u.ra, u.dec, u.mag
7:38:06.27 22:04:47.4 5.46
>>> print ephem.constellation(u)
('Gem', 'Gemini')
```

Comment: In a perfect world, you'd be able to use the `ephem` library to find out the Zodiac sign by simply replacing Uranus with Sun in your example. However, it appears that the signs and the constellations [don't match up exactly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zodiac#Table_of_dates). There is also an astrology-specific Python library called [oroboros](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oroboros/20080712), but it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 8):

Using bisect is more efficient than iterating until you find a match, but a lookup table for each day of the year is faster still and really not that big.

```
from bisect import bisect
signs = [(1,20,"Cap"), (2,18,"Aqu"), (3,20,"Pis"), (4,20,"Ari"),
         (5,21,"Tau"), (6,21,"Gem"), (7,22,"Can"), (8,23,"Leo"),
         (9,23,"Vir"), (10,23,"Lib"), (11,22,"Sco"), (12,22,"Sag"),
         (12,31,"Cap")]
def zodiac_sign(m,d):
    return signs[bisect(signs,(m,d))][2]

assert zodiac_sign(3,9) == "Pis"
assert zodiac_sign(6,30) == "Can"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var ZZ=[1231,1222,1122,1023,923,823,722,621,521,420,321,220,121];

var ZN=['Capricorn','Sagittarius','Scorpio','Libra','Virgo','Leo','Cancer', 'Gemini','Taurus','Aries','Pisces','Aquarius','Capricorn'];

var d8=new Date();

var m=d8.getMonth()+1;

var d=d8.getDate();

//m=1;d=1

var mdd=parseInt(''+m+(d<9?'0'+d:d));

var i=0;while(ZZ[i]&gt;mdd && i&lt;ZZ.length){i++}--i;

var RV='Born '+m+'/'+d+' - Star Sign: '+ZN[i];RV
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def zodiac(day,month):
    signs=[('Capricorn',19),('Aquarius',18),('Pisces',20),('Aries',19),('Taurus',20),('Gemini',20) ,('Cancer',22),('Leo',22) ,('Virgo',22) ,('Libra',22) ,('Scorpio',21),('Sagittarius',21),('Capricorn',)]
    if(day<=signs[month-1][1]):
        return signs[month-1][0]
    else:
        return signs[month][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres my algo without using a loop (JS logic: using a js object )

```
var zods = {
            0:{limit:21,vals:["aqu","cap"]},
            1:{limit:20,vals:["pis","aqu"]},
            2:{limit:21,vals:["ari","pis"]},
            3:{limit:21,vals:["tau","ari"]},
            4:{limit:21,vals:["gem","tau"]},
            5:{limit:21,vals:["can","gem"]},
            6:{limit:22,vals:["leo","can"]},
            7:{limit:22,vals:["vir","leo"]},
            8:{limit:22,vals:["lib","vir"]},
            9:{limit:22,vals:["sco","lib"]},
            10:{limit:23,vals:["sag","sco"]},
            11:{limit:22,vals:["cap","sag"]}
            };

        var dt = new Date();
        var zodObj = zods[dt.getMonth()];
        return dt.getDate()>=zodObj.limit?zodObj.vals[0]:zodObj.vals[1];
```